# Waffle Framework:Login pop up on session timeout in internet explorer on windows 7/8 Issue

Tags: java

I am facing with the problem in my web application where I am asked to enter my login credentials again on session time out.This issue arises on Windows7 and Windows 8 Internet Explorer only.
Ideally what I want is that the pop up for credentials should not arise and user should be automatically logged in after session time out .

Note: 
1>Single Sign-On works well with other browsers like Firefox on Windows 7 and 8 as well(No login pop up issues here).
2>It also works fine with Internet Explorer on Windows Xp. 
3>My web application uses Weblogic server 10.3, waffle-jna jar version 1.5 and I am running it on Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.
4>I have tried with the latest versions of Waffle (ver 1.7.3 and ver 1.6) in my web app but still I am facing the same problem.

To sum up ,  On windows 7 and windows 8  with the browser Internet explorer Single Sign-On fails and I am asked to enter the login credentials on session time out.Is this the issue with Waffle framework? Please provide any help.

Comment: have you found a workaround for this ? I'm facing the same issue